# Haskell combine two lists incrementing the size of each chunk from each list every time

Tags: haskell

Need to create a function in Haskell that takes two lists and yields
a list combining all the elements in the two input lists, taking 1 from the first list, 2 from the second list, 3 from the first list, 4 from the second list, etc,until both are exhausted.

Example:

```
weaveHunks [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
=> [1,11,12,2,3,4,13,14,15,16,5,6,7,8,17,18]
```

I have a function so far that given a number n and two lists it will, combine both given lists together in chunks that are of size n.

```
weaveHunks :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
weaveHunks _ xs [] = xs
weaveHunks _ [] ys = ys
weaveHunks n xs ys = xHunk ++ yHunk ++ weaveHunks n xRemain yRemain
 where [(xHunk, xRemain), (yHunk, yRemain)] = splitAt n <$> [xs,ys]
```

Trying to expand on this answer so instead of giving it a parameter that defines the chunk size I want to increment a counter everytime the function is called recursively.

This is where I am not sure how would you go about creating some sort of counter that increases the chunk size everytime the function is called. I can't pass a number to the function above as its only two parameters are the two lists. I thought about using some sort of auxiliary function that would keep a incrementing a counter each time weaveHunks runs but I don't think that's a feasible option either.

Is there a different way that does not rely on a incrementing a counter? I feel like i should be using the `succ` operator to accomplish what i am trying to do

Comment: Hi and welcome! To understand correctly your question: you have a main function `weaveHunks :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` (the "function above as its only two parameters are two lists") and you have *another* auxiliary function which should have another name, f.e. `weaveHunksAux :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`, right?

Comment: Hi, you're correct about the main function weaveHunks, takes in two lists and outputs a list which is result of weaving both given lists together, increasing the size of each chunk from the two given lists each time. The auxiliary function was just my idea about how I could somehow keep a counter so i could increase the size of the chunks each time, It's not part of the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably missing here is an accumulator that increments, such that we know how much to take from the first and the second list.

If I understood it correct, there are basically two cases here:

1. in case both lists are exhausted, the result is an empty list; and
2. if at least one of the two lists is not empty, we take `n` elements from the first list, `n+1` elements from the second list, and we recurse on the remaining elements of the lists, but now with `n+2`, so that means we define a function like:

```
import Data.List(splitAt)

weaveHunks :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
weaveHunks = go 1
    where go _ [] [] = []
          go n la lb = aa ++ ba ++ go (n+2) ab bb
              where (aa, ab) = splitAt n la
                    (ba, bb) = splitAt (n+1) lb
```

Or like [@ThomasM.DuBuisson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934348/haskell-combine-two-lists-incrementing-the-size-of-each-chunk-from-each-list-eve/53934762?noredirect=1#comment94709677_53934762) and [@DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934348/haskell-combine-two-lists-incrementing-the-size-of-each-chunk-from-each-list-eve/53934762?noredirect=1#comment94719210_53934762) suggest, we can each time take `n` from the first list, and recurse with `n+1` and *swap* the lists, like:

```
import Data.List(splitAt)

weaveHunks :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
weaveHunks = go 1
    where go _ [] [] = []
          go n la lb = aa ++ go (n+1) lb ab
              where (aa, ab) = splitAt n la
```

Comment: Can you just pass `n+1` and recursive call with `go (n+1) lb ab`?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: but the next time we take `3` elements from the first list if I understood it correctly. We can indeed do that, and multiply with `2` at the `splitAt` level. But I'm not sure this makes it more elegant.

Comment: You are correct with your understanding of the question, your solution is what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No need to multiply by 2. `go n la lb = aa ++ go (n+1) lb ab where (aa, ab) = splitAt n la` is a drop-in replacement (keep the base case, of course). Try it and see.